# Is there a way to find when a value was inserted into a particular cell on an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, audit

There is a specific row in a table that I would like to research. I'd like to know when this row was inserted, when its individual fields were modified, the various values each field in this row might have had etc.. In short, its audit.. Is it possible ? How ?..

I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: you don't provide enough information... what Oracle version ? How is audit configured on the DB (settings etc.) ? Is Flashback enabled ?

Comment: version - 11g. What other settings would u like to know ?.. It'd be helpful if you can also mention how to find those, as i'm not very familiar with oracle..

Comment: in Oracle there is an option to configure an "audit-trail" (several settings...), is that enable ? what are the settings of the audit-trail ? do have Flashback (another oracle option) enabled/configured?

Comment: There may be ways to configure these things (as @Yahia's comments have indicated), but they're not available by default. So if it's something that's already occurred, you're likely out of luck (unless someone else changed the default configuration)

Comment: FLASHBACK_ON is set to 'NO'..

Answer (score 2):

You can enable [auditing](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm). If this is after the fact, no I don't think there's much you can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [LogMiner](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/LogMiner.php) after the fact, but that depends on whether you've got access to the necessary redo log files.